# Android App Link verify does not work all the time

Tags: android

I am testing Android [App Link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations) feature.

I believe I have everything setup for App Link feature to work, and, yes indeed, it has worked. However, sometimes it doesn't work. I'm including logs while installing the App Link target app.

The below is failed log

```
12-12 19:41:51.465 4858-24962/? I/SingleHostAsyncVerifier: Verification result: checking for a statement with source a <
  a: "https://noblapp.com"
>
, relation delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls, and target b <
  a: "com.cheil.sumtssotest"
  b <
    a: "34:83:BE:17:38:AA:F3:DA:7C:0C:06:B9:57:19:12:2D:B9:2D:38:2F:36:FE:92:BF:4D:E9:FA:88:D4:C7:62:77"
  >
>
 --> false.
12-12 19:41:51.465 4858-24204/? I/IntentFilterIntentOp: Verification 29 complete. Success:false. Failed hosts:noblapp.com.
```

The below is success log.

```
12-12 19:49:25.404 4858-28780/? I/SingleHostAsyncVerifier: Verification result: checking for a statement with source a <
  a: "https://noblapp.com"
>
, relation delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls, and target b <
  a: "com.cheil.sumtssotest"
  b <
    a: "34:83:BE:17:38:AA:F3:DA:7C:0C:06:B9:57:19:12:2D:B9:2D:38:2F:36:FE:92:BF:4D:E9:FA:88:D4:C7:62:77"
  >
>
 --> true.
12-12 19:49:25.405 4858-28745/? I/IntentFilterIntentOp: Verification 32 complete. Success:true. Failed hosts:.
```

The two occasions happened while installing exactly same app. Install -> delete -> install again.

The assetlinks.json is located at https://noblapp.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json.

And the test app is setup to accept 'https://noblapp.com' URL view intent.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="noblapp.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The tested Android is 8.1.0 (Galaxy Note 9)

Please help!

Comment: Have you resolved this?  I get a 404 when attempting to navigate to your assetlinks file.

Comment: Also getting this issue with Android 10. Sometimes true, sometimes false returned in `SingleHostAsyncVerifier: Verification result` when installing the same app.